# Ignore HTML with str_replace

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I'm trying to replace spaces with an underscore (_) with str_replace but it also affects HTML tags.

My code:

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_facet_html', function( $output, $params ) {
    if ( 'blog_tags' == $params['facet']['name'] ) {
        $output = str_replace(' ', '_', $output);
    }
    return $output;
}, 10, 2 );
```

The expected result was:

```
<div class="checkbox">Dynamic_String_Exemple<span class="counter">1</span></div>
```

but it returns:

```
<div_class="checkbox">Dynamic_String_Exemple<span_class="counter">1</span></div>
```

`div_class` `span_class`

What's the best way to prevent this?

Comment: You prevent this by parsing html with an html parser.  How might your input vary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only have one sample string to build from, so I make no guarantees that this will work for all cases in your project, but...

You should use a dom parsing technique because basic string function targeting will be more error prone in valid html.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IlgBe))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="checkbox">Dynamic_String_Exemple<span class="counter">1</span></div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$firstDivFirstNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0);
$firstDivFirstNode->nodeValue = str_replace(' ', '_', $firstDivFirstNode->nodeValue);
echo trim($dom->saveHTML());
```